# Oracle SQL - How to determine if the difference between two dates is less than one minute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a need to determine in SQL whether the difference between two dates is less that 60 seconds. So I want in pseudo SQL:

```
IF DATE1 - DATE2 < 60 seconds THEN
    -- do something
END IF;
```

The problem I am facing is that date differences are not expressed in number but in date formats not easily evaluated against a value expressed in numbers. How can I make this evaluation in SQL?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
where abs(date1 - date2) < 1 / (24 * 60)
```

or:

```
where date1 > date2 - interval '60' second and
      date1 < date2 + interval '60' second
```